# Setting Header for CORS AJAX Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

I'm trying to make a AJAX call from one server, to a JSON call on another server. I've read about setting the header for CORS, but not sure specifically I need to do. I'm on Server A making a call to Server B and get an error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://serverB No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://serverA' is therefore not allowed access.

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'http://serverB/userList',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){

        alert(text.html(JSON.stringify(data)));

    },
    error: function(e){

        alert(e);
    }

});
```

I've seen a lot of different ways to add to the header, but not sure what the proper way is as results are mixed (searched StackOverflow for examples).

What is the proper way to add to the example AJAX call above?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: What server are you working with? .Net (c#), Linux PHP?

Comment: If you're server is configured correctly, jQuery should take care of this auto-magically.

Comment: it's a Ubuntu Linux server. The project is set up as a PHP but basically using straight HTML and JQuery with the above AJAX call

Comment: Using the jsonp datatype, you shouldn't be having problems with CORS.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid jsonp all together. it's not safe anymore... And people who want to use another rest api built today with jsonp might get suspicious.

In php you should add the headers that are necessary before you send any data

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

It's also possible to add it in .htaccess or Appache

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

just make sure you don't add it to anything you don't want to share

And then there is also the shorthand method of jQuery json ajax

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>

<script>
$.getJSON("https://api.github.com", function(res){
  $('pre').html(JSON.stringify(res, null, "  "))
})
</script>
```

and my favorit [Fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) without any dependency

```html
<pre></pre>

<script>
  fetch("https://api.github.com")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => { 
    
      var pre = document.querySelector("pre");
      pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(json, null, "  ")
      
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I have seen, both the client and the server need to be on the 'same page' when it comes to CORS.  In the past on the server side I have had to open up Origins, Headers, and Methods to `*` at least get it working and then come back and restrict it down from there to the proper domains and methods.

In .Net, WepApi I have used `EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true }` to get me to that point.

In Apache it could be something like this in your apache.conf

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

Comment: It's a Linux + PHP stack so not sure this is relevant.

Comment: @timothyclifford he actually mentions Apache

Comment: To his credit, I add it after the server type question as answered